# angularjs changes in data not affected in views ajax

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I am developing an application with angular js

Question: When I have an ajax call to server and I need to change the views based on the result of ajax call, the views don't get affected by this call, I think it the page renders before ajax call is finished but I don't know how to resolve it

For example the following piece of code

```
 $scope.addItem = function() {
    $http({
       method  :'GET',
       url : 'addItem',
       headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
    }).success( function(data) {
        $scope.allItems = data;         
    });
}
```

the allItems changed after the ajax call but the view is not changed 
how should I solve this?

Comment: Is `allitems` bound to the view?

Comment: Try a $scope.$apply() after you set the data in success.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code. You probably have not correctly bound the allItems variable to the view or data is a complex object and you have to take a property from it like data.people or something similar.

Comment: Please include the HTML of this page as well. Your Angular code looks fine and there is nothing wrong with it. Also, try a `console.log` inside your `success()` call to see if the `$http` request is executed successfully.

Comment: Another thought.  Are you sure that your view uses the right scope?

Comment: i dont see where you are even attempting to change the view - i think u need something like `$location.path("/path/to/partial");` in your success function.

Comment: all you are doing right now on `success` is setting a `$scope` variable - doesn't really have anything to do with what page it goes to.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you need something like `$scope.addItem = function() {
    $http({
       method  :'GET',
       url : 'addItem',
       headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
    }).success( function(data) {
        $scope.allItems = data; $location.path("path/to/template");
    });
}`